# How to handle nested json objects/arrays in android using retrofit and gson?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

This is my json object structure:

```
   object   {1}

      products  [3]

            0   {14}

            1   {14}

            2   {14}
```

and here is my code:

gitapi.java

```
public interface gitapi {
    @GET("/admin/API/{user}")
    public void getFeed(@Path("user") String user, Callback<gitmodel> response);    
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Button click;
TextView tv;
EditText edit_user;
ProgressBar pbar;
String API = "http://xxyyzz.com";                         //BASE URL

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    edit_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user = edit_user.getText().toString();
            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Retrofit section start from here...
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(API).build();                                        //create an adapter for retrofit with base url

            gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);                            //creating a service for adapter with our GET class

            //Now ,we need to call for response
            //Retrofit using gson for JSON-POJO conversion

            git.getFeed(user, new Callback<gitmodel>() {
                @Override
                public void success(gitmodel gitmodel, Response response) {
                    //we get json object from github server to our POJO or model class

                    tv.setText("getTitle :" + gitmodel.getTitle());

                    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                               //disable progressbar
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv.setText(error.getMessage());
                    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                               //disable progressbar
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is I dont know how to access the inner json objects. Is there a way to do this.

from jsonschemaa2pojo.com i got the pojo file as 2 files one for gitmodel.java and other for product.java. My Question is how can i access the objects within the json object.

Ex: you can see the tv.setText("getTitle :" + gitmodel.getTitle()); in MainActivity.java which is what i want to achieve. i want to call the methods in order to access the inner object.
Thank you...

Comment: `gitmodel.getInnerObject()` ... or `gitmodel.getObjectList().get(x)` ... there are bazillions topic about json, please don't be lazy and do some reasearch before asking

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to access each elements of the json object however nested and complex it is. In this case i want to access the elements of the inner object.

Comment: `gitmodel.getInnerObject()` should returns `InnerModel`(similar to gitmodel but should define inner complex property)... `InnerModel` should have `innerproperty` and setter/getter ... so now you can use `gitmodel.getInnerObject().getInnerProperty()` ... in other words: **you have to define class for every complex type** ... please use google to search an examples ... **or at least read gson documentation**

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I might be doing something wrong. This is what i did: I created the gitmodel class which contains a getProducts() and setProducts() and a seperate product class with all setter/getter methods in it. Now i tried making a method in gitmodel which says getInnerObjectElements() in which i create a product object and call the product.getElement() to get the innerObject's Elements. I am a noob. Please help me out. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to create POJO using this link : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

In this link select **Source type: JSON** and **Annotation style: GSON** and after that click on **preview** it will create pojo as per your Json and you will easily parse json.